# Treating output from one bash script as a file in another bash script

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

There are a few questions on this site phrased similarly, but none quite get at what I need.

I have a script that processes data from some file, in a manner something like ...

```
infile=$1
grep foo $infile
#process line(s) containing "foo"
grep bar $infile
#process line(s) containing "bar"
grep yyy $infile
grep zzz $infile
#process together lines containing yyy and zzz
```

My question is, I would like for infile to be replaced with the output from another script.  I would rather not store the output in a temporary file.  How do I do this?  Is there a way?  I thought about a named pipe but when I do that the script hangs after the first grep command (which, at least, is successful).  I haven't been able to find any other way.

Comment: If you want to grep it multiple times, you'll need a temporary file.

Comment: Better to work out an approach that only needs to read the output once.

Comment: If the patterns such as `foo`, `bar` ... are deterministic (not dynamic),
you can say something like: `grep -f <(printf "foo\nbar\nzzz\n") <(./another_script)`.

Comment: simple answer .... run `another script` multiple times; assuming you only want to run `another script` once but process the output 4x times then you'll need some sort of intermediate 'storage' (eg, file, in-memory array) but then we need to know what you mean by 'process line(s) containing "???"; this looks (to me) like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and would probably benefit from knowing more details on the form of the output from `another script` and how said output is to be processed

Answer (score 0):

The command to do that is `awk`:

```
infile=$1
awk '
  /foo/ { #process line(s) containing "foo"}
  /bar/ { #process line(s) containing "bar"}
  /yyy/ && /zzz/ { #process together lines containing yyy and zzz}
' $infile
```